# CSV containing GeoJSON format geometries to DataFrame

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, shapely

I have a CSV file I open as a DataFrame.
Among the columns is one named `geom 1` :

```
df.loc[:, 'geom 1']
>>>
0       {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[2.826589...
1       {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[2.225689...
2       {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[2.225689...
3       {'type': 'MultiPolygon', 'coordinates': [[[[5....
4       {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[3.933055...
                              ...                        
2998                                                 None
2999                                                  NaN
3000    {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[5.014937...
3001    {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[4.912995...
3002    {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[4.739631...
Name: geom 1, Length: 3003, dtype: object

#Conditionning the dataframe :
df.replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

I would like to convert these strings to geometries in a GeoDataFrame.

After a few resarches I did not find a working solution :

[TypeError: Input geometry column must contain valid geometry objects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327197/typeerror-input-geometry-column-must-contain-valid-geometry-objects) :

```
df.loc[:, 'geom 1'] = df.loc[:, 'geom 1'].apply(wkt.loads) 
>>> ParseException: Unknown type: '{'TYPE':'
WKTReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.
```

[Convert GeoJSON to GeoPandas GeoDataframe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174159/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-geodataframe) :

```
df.replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
geom = [shape(i) for i in df.loc[:, 'geom 1'].dropna()]
>>> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What I succeded was to sent the DataFrame to PostGIS, convert the type of the column `geom 1` from text to `geometry` and use the function `ST_FromGeoJson` to access the geometry.
Since I have many columns `geom` I want to do this under python in order to merge all the columns `geom` into a single one named `all_geoms`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shape function from shapely needs a dictionary, so you need to parse the strings to dictionaries before calling shape. If you have these imports

```
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import shape
```

and you define this function

```
def parse_geom(geom_str):
    try:
        return shape(json.loads(geom_str))
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):  # Handle NaN and empty strings
        return None
```

Then this should give you a GeoDataframe

```
df["geom 1"] = df["geom 1"].apply(parse_geom)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="geom 1")
```

Worked example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import json
from shapely.geometry import shape

def parse_geom(geom_str):
    try:
        return shape(json.loads(geom_str))
    except (TypeError, AttributeError):  # Handle NaN and empty strings
        return None

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your.csv')
df["geom 1"] = df["geom 1"].apply(parse_geom)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="geom 1")
print(gdf.head())
```

Comment: I get this Error : `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: @Basile: It is because of the single quotes around property names in the json. You can try to replace the single quotes. The last line in the `parse_geom` function becomes `return shape(json.loads(geom_str.replace("'", '"')))`. This can be a bit dangerous if the values of the json object contains double quotes. I don't think it is a problem in your case. Another option is to use the ast module. First import it with `import ast`. The last line in `parse_geom` is then: `return shape(ast.literal_eval(geom_str))`